# How to download an excel sheet which is fetched from Sharepoint List using javascript on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, ajax, sharepoint

I have my excel file in the sharepoint list. I am trying to create a functionality that can download this excel file when I click the anchor tag. For Eg

```
<a class="btnDownload" href="\text.xlsx"></a>

$('.btnDownload').click(function(){

//Not sure on what I need to do to download this excel-file

})
```

Answer (score 0):

microsoft provide documentation for sharepoint js-api , checkout bellow link (search Read a file in a document library)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-sharepoint-javascript-apis-to-work-with-sharepoint-data